# Google Address Validation API to Magento 2 Using Avalara Avatax

Tags: google-address-validation-api

Has anyone else had a problem integrating Google's Address Validation API into Magento 2's Avalara Avatax?  It's almost as if the API key is restricted.  Although it's currently unrestricted.  Our shipping and handling/tax amounts are all off.  I think it's because the address isn't being validated by Google's new address validation system for Avalara Avatax (Using Ma agento 2 website platform).

Just looked at what I thought the API key was that the developers used and it appears to be unrestricted. Also, I checked the configuration panel on Magento admin and it appears to be correctly set up.
https://developer.avalara.com/api-reference/avatax/rest/v2/methods/Addresses/ResolveAddress/

Answer (score 0):

Google's [Address Validation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/address-validation) can be used [with API keys](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/address-validation/get-api-key) or [OAuth 2.0 service accounts](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/address-validation/oauth_token).

In either case, [the API project must be set up](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/address-validation/cloud-setup) with both billing and the Address Validation API itself enabled.

The Address Validation API only supports two types of API key restrictions: IP address and API restrictions. Other types of API key restrictions are not supported.

If all the above checks pass and the Address Validation API still does not accept your API key, I recommend you [contact the support team](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/address-validation/support#contact-maps-support) for 1:1 assistance.